# Using variables in regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a list of strings structured like:

```
C:/Users/scott-filter1.pgm C:/Users/scott-filter2.pgm C:/Users/scott-filter3.pgm
```

Essentially, what I want to do is remove `C:/Users/scott-` and `.pgm` leaving me with just `filter1` for example.

So, this is my regular expression:

```
regsub -nocase {.pgm} [regsub -nocase {C:/Users/scott-} $list ""] ""
```

Which works fine, albeit a little clunky. Now, when I replace the inner regular expression with a regular expression that contains a variable, such as:

```
set myname scott 
{C:/Users/$myname-}
```

It no longer works. Any ideas on how to achieve what I want to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove the braces as they prevent substitution (that is you won't have the variable replaced by the value of that variable and instead, you will have the literal string `$myname` in the regex -- also might be worth noting that `$` in regex matches at the end of the string):

```
regsub "C:/Users/$myname-" $in "" out
```

Or you can do it with a single `regsub`:

```
set list "C:/Users/scott-filter1.pgm"
set myname "scott"
regsub -nocase -- "C:/Users/$myname-(.*)\\.pgm" $list {\1} out
puts $out
# => filter1
```

Notes:

- If you remove the braces and use quotes, you need to double escape things you would otherwise escape once.
- I'm using a capture group when I use parens and `.*` matches any character(s). The captured part is then put back using `\1` in the replacement part, into the variable called `out`.
- Strictly speaking, you need to escape `.` because this is a wildcard in regex and matches any 1 character. Because I'm using quotes, I need to double escape it with two backslashes.
- Matching might be easier and more straightforward than substitution:

  ```
  regexp -nocase -- "C:/Users/$myname-(.*)\\.pgm" $list - out
  puts $out
  # => filter1
  ```
- If the 'name' can be anything, then you can use a more generic regex to avoid having to place the name in the regex... For instance, if `$myname` can never have a dash, you can use the negated class `[^-]` which matches anything except dash and you won't have to worry about double escapes:

  ```
  regexp -nocase -- {C:/Users/[^-]+-(.*)\.pgm} $list - out
  puts $out
  # => filter1
  ```

Comment: The only issue I experienced is with a list that contains more than 1 entry. For me, it treated the entire list as one string, removing `"C:/Users/$myname-"` from the first entry, and `".pgm"` from the last entry. I just had a simple `foreach` loop handle each entry individually. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter Ah, I didn't give it a thought that `$list` was an *actual* list! Are all your strings of the same format? (i.e. like  `C:/Users/$myname-{something here}.pgm` where `$myname` and `{something here}` cannot contain dashes/hyphens). If so, you can use a single regex like: `set results [regexp -all -inline -- {[^-]+(?=\.pgm)} $list]` and receive all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this, assuming the part you want is always in a file name between a dash and the last dot before the extension.

```
set foo C:/Users/scott-filter1.pgm
# => C:/Users/scott-filter1.pgm
set bar [file rootname [file tail $foo]]
# => scott-filter1
set baz [split $bar -]
# => scott filter1
set qux [lindex $baz end]
# => filter1
```

or

```
lindex [split [file rootname [file tail $foo]] -] end
# => filter1
```

The `file` commands work on any string that is recognizable as a file path. `file tail` yields the file path minus the part with the directories, i.e. only the actual file name. `file rootname` yields the file name minus the extension. `split` converts the string into a list, splitting it at every dash. `lindex` gets one item from the list, in this case the last item.

An even more ad-hoc-ish (but actually quite generic) solution:

```
lindex [split [lindex [split $foo -] end] .] 0
# => filter1
```

This invocation splits the file path at every dash and selects the last item. This item is again split at every dot, and the first item of the resulting list is selected.

Documentation: [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a list of filenames, we can use `lmap` (to apply an operation to each of the elements of a list, requires 8.6) and `file` (specifically `file tail` and `file rootname`) to do most of the work. A simple `string map` will finish it off, though a `regsub` could also have been used.

```
set filenames {C:/Users/scott-filter1.pgm C:/Users/scott-filter2.pgm C:/Users/scott-filter3.pgm}
set filtered [lmap name $filenames {
    string map {"scott-" ""} [file rootname [file tail $name]]
    # Regsub version:
    #regsub {^scott-} [file rootname [file tail $name]] ""
}]
```

Older versions of Tcl will need to use `foreach`:

```
set filtered {}
foreach name $filenames {
    lappend filtered [string map {"scott-" ""} [file rootname [file tail $name]]]
    # Regsub version:
    #lappend filtered [regsub {^scott-} [file rootname [file tail $name]] ""]
}
```